# Requests through a proxy with Scrapy doesn't seem to work, am I missing something?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I've been trying to scrape using a proxy but I can't seem to make it work,

My settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'linkmailscraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['linkmailscraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'linkmailscraper.spiders'

# Retry many times since proxies often fail
RETRY_TIMES = 5
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
'linkmailscraper.randomproxy.RandomProxy': 100,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 700,
}
PROXY_MODE = 0
PROXY_LIST = get_proxies()
# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
# USER_AGENT = 'linkmailscraper (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

get_proxies() function returns a list of proxies to use with the following format:
'http://... : ...'

and finally, the spider itself in the script:

```
class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'email' 
    path = file_path

    proxy_list = get_proxies()

    def parse(self, response):

        #  link extractor object (LxmlLinkExtractor), that checks for new URLs inside a source.
        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)
        links = [str(link.url) for link in links]
        links.append(str(response.url))

        # parsing multiple requests for our link list from the parse method to parse_link
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link, dont_filter=True)
        ...
```

And randomproxy.py:

```
class Mode:
    RANDOMIZE_PROXY_EVERY_REQUESTS, RANDOMIZE_PROXY_ONCE, SET_CUSTOM_PROXY = 
range(3)


class RandomProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.mode = settings.get('PROXY_MODE')
        self.proxy_list = settings.get('PROXY_LIST')
        print(self.proxy_list)
        self.chosen_proxy = ''
        if self.mode == Mode.RANDOMIZE_PROXY_EVERY_REQUESTS or self.mode == 
Mode.RANDOMIZE_PROXY_ONCE:
            if self.proxy_list is None:
                raise KeyError('PROXY_LIST setting is missing.')
            self.proxies = {}
            fin = open(self.proxy_list)
            try:
                for line in fin.readlines():
                    parts = re.match('(\w+://)([^:]+?:[^@]+?@)?(.+)', 
line.strip())
                    if not parts:
                        continue

                    # Cut trailing @
                    if parts.group(2):
                        user_pass = parts.group(2)[:-1]
                    else:
                        user_pass = ''

                    self.proxies[parts.group(1) + parts.group(3)] = user_pass
            finally:
                fin.close()
            if self.mode == Mode.RANDOMIZE_PROXY_ONCE:
                self.chosen_proxy = random.choice(list(self.proxies.keys()))
        elif self.mode == Mode.SET_CUSTOM_PROXY:
            custom_proxy = settings.get('CUSTOM_PROXY')
            self.proxies = {}
            parts = re.match('(\w+://)([^:]+?:[^@]+?@)?(.+)', 
custom_proxy.strip())
            if not parts:
                raise ValueError('CUSTOM_PROXY is not well formatted')

            if parts.group(2):
                user_pass = parts.group(2)[:-1]
            else:
                user_pass = ''

            self.proxies[parts.group(1) + parts.group(3)] = user_pass
            self.chosen_proxy = parts.group(1) + parts.group(3)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Don't overwrite with a random one (server-side state for IP)
        print("Starting crawl with Proxy.")
        if 'proxy' in request.meta:
            if request.meta["exception"] is False:
                return
        request.meta["exception"] = False
        if len(self.proxies) == 0:
            raise ValueError('All proxies are unusable, cannot proceed')

        if self.mode == Mode.RANDOMIZE_PROXY_EVERY_REQUESTS:
            proxy_address = random.choice(list(self.proxies.keys()))
        else:
            proxy_address = self.chosen_proxy

        proxy_user_pass = self.proxies[proxy_address]

        if proxy_user_pass:
            request.meta['proxy'] = proxy_address
            basic_auth = 'Basic ' + 
base64.b64encode(proxy_user_pass.encode()).decode()
            request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = basic_auth
        else:
            log.debug('Proxy user pass not found')
        log.debug('Using proxy <%s>, %d proxies left' % (
                proxy_address, len(self.proxies)))

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        if 'proxy' not in request.meta:
            return
        if self.mode == Mode.RANDOMIZE_PROXY_EVERY_REQUESTS or self.mode == Mode.RANDOMIZE_PROXY_ONCE:
            proxy = request.meta['proxy']
            try:
                del self.proxies[proxy]
            except KeyError:
                pass
            request.meta["exception"] = True
            if self.mode == Mode.RANDOMIZE_PROXY_ONCE:
                self.chosen_proxy = random.choice(list(self.proxies.keys()))
            log.info('Removing failed proxy <%s>, %d proxies left' % (
                proxy, len(self.proxies)))
```

Something is off, and all the requests are done through my public IP and not through any of the proxies in the list (I tried setting a single proxy but that also doesn't work). Any ideas for other things I cant try?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to your priorities of the middleware. You have used `'linkmailscraper.randomproxy.RandomProxy': 600`, which make it to be used last, even after the download is done.

So either lower it or change `'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110` to `'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 700` so your proxy gets picked first

Comment: I tried switching the priorities but the script still using my public IP. I noticed that the PROXY_LIST in settings.py and the RandomProxy object itself don't really do anything here.

Comment: Your class name is `ProxyMiddleware` and middleware you configured is `RandomProxy`?

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I updated the DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES.  RandomProxy is in the file randomproxy.py and acts as the middleware.

Comment: Can you debug if your middleware is being used fine? Because if ordering is correct it should work